# Saving a csv file with sinatra and datamapper

Tags: ruby, sinatra, carrierwave, datamapper

Trying to do as the title says using carrierwave but not having much luck as i get the following error:

```
TypeError - no implicit conversion of CsvFile into String:
```

here is my post method where it fails:

```
post '/file' do
  file_data = params[:csv_file][:tempfile]
  file_name = params[:csv_file][:filename]
  file_path = "app/public/csv_files/#{file_name}"
  date = Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
  csv_file = CsvFile.new(name: file_name,
                         path: file_path,
                         date: date,
                         file: file_data
                        )
  file = CSV_File_Reader.new(file_path)
  erb(:finished)
end
```

and here is my CsvFile class:

```
class CsvFile
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
  property :path, String
  property :date, String

  mount_uploader :file, File

  has n, :images

end
```

All the params come through as they should but as I'm fairly new to this I'm clearly missing something and googling hasn't worked for me. Any help would be great. Thanks